# I have a form action done in thymeleaf but the endpoint defined there is not being called in the controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a form submission using thymeleaf and springboot, which I have done many times before but for some reason this one specific endpoint cannot be reached. I feel it might have something to do with it being a nested endpoint or something like that but any help with it would be appreciated.

The thymeleaf portion I'm having trouble with can be found below:

```
<form id="application" th:action="@{/admin/addApplication}" th:object="${application}" method="post">
    <h1>Add Application</h1>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="applicationName" placeholder="Application Name" required>
        <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password to access application" required>
        <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt' ></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="file" id="img" name="image" accept="image/*" placeholder="Upload Display Image">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select name="applicationType" id="Application Type">
            <option value="admin">Navigation</option>
            <option value="user">Waste Management</option>
            <option value="user">Energy Consumption</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register Application</button>
</form>
```

And the corresponding controller looks like this:

```
@Data
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

    @GetMapping("/application")
    public String adminLanding(Model model) {
        return "addApplication";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addApplication")
    public String addApplication(@ModelAttribute Application application){
        applicationRepository.save(application);
        return "addApplication";
    }

}
```

Comment: This code looks good for me and should work fine. Maybe the controller class is not on the component scan path? Check the package structure. If you have the actuator you can call actuator/beans endpoint and search for ApplicationController.

Comment: I wonder who is downvoting all the questions without giving any reason in the comment?

Comment: Why did you put @Data above your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, it had to with my upload. Probably messed up how I handled that but once I removed it, the page was redirected successfully.